# How do you defeat the ender dragon with a stone sword

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I kill the Ender Dragon using a stone sword?

Comment: *patiently*. Also, 20,000 hp will use up 4 stone swords, unless you use unbreaking III.

Comment: Most definatly want dat unbreaking, with some sharpness, and don't forget other enchantments (I think fire affects the Dragon to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you would normally, really. Keep in mind the durability of the sword and make sure to bring blocks to tower up the pillars to destroy the crystals. When the dragon swoops down, be sure to jump up and down to get a critical hit for maximum damage.

Answer (score 2):

You could get it low with normal tools (a bow, diamond sword) and then get the last blow with a stone sword.